# Errors using ng-repeat to display data in view AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display some data from an array in the view using ng-repeat but it does not work.

This is how my html looks:

```
<div>
        <p>loop here</p>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in transferTest">{{item.Marks}}</li>
            <li>{{item}}</li>
            <li>{{item.Marks}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And this is how my controller looks:

```
 $scope.resultsArray.push({"Module_Code": $scope.moduleCode, "Marks" :$scope.marks,"Recommendation" :$scope.moduleRecommendation})                                       
  $rootScope.transferTest = $scope.resultsArray;
```

Basically this is how my data is organized:

```
[
{"Module_Code": "IT", "Marks": "70", "Recommendation": "test"}
{"Module_Code": "ACC", "Marks": "30","Recommendation": "testintuber"}

It seems that I am unable to access the $rootScope.transferTest from the view.
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a transferTest defined in some other scope below rootScope? Does it need to be in rootScope at all? If it needs to be shared it would be much better to use a service for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not properly formated,

it should be,

```
[
{"Module_Code": "IT", "Marks": "70", "Recommendation": "test"},
{"Module_Code": "ACC", "Marks": "30","Recommendation": "testintuber"}]
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/AOPQQE9vHmLqDZkPFFcQ?p=preview)**

Comment: @sanjeetharan I updated the JSON, but it is still not working.

Comment: @purplewind Check the demo attached

Comment: @sanjeetharan My code is very similar to yours, but the <ul> object just refuse to display the <li> with the ng-repeat.Any idea roughly why this is happening ? I am thinking maybe the view page is initialize before the data is even written into the $rootScope.

Comment: Can I take team viewer ?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is malformed:
[
{"Module_Code"= "IT", "Marks": "70", "Recommendation": "test"}
{"Module_Code**:**= "ACC", "Marks**:** "30","Recommendation:= "testintuber